# After adding HereMaps ipa file size is increased from 10 MB to 300 MB

Tags: ios, here-api

I am developing IOS APP we have the requirement to use heremap in the app. After adding here map framework my ipa file size is increased from 10mb to 300mb. I noticed that NMAKit.framework folder it self showing 517 MB

To integrate here map framework in my project i followed the instructions from https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-starter/topics/app-create-simple.html

Is there any way to decrease the size of my ipa file?

Answer (score 0):

The framework contains all architectures, that's why it's quite big. In the end, the app deployed on the phone will only get the target architecture. So the 300MB are not what ends up on the device.

You can strip out manually the emulator architectures from your IPA via the included strip_sim.sh file.

You can also remove unneeded fonts, as described here https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics/size-management.html which will also give you some more MB.

Comment: 517 MB showing after deleting the emulator architectures previously it showing 574 MB, if we remove the fonts we can save only 5 MB.

Comment: As said, the framework contains severa architectures, since it supports all iphones and simulators. In the end, this is NOT what ends on your device. build the ipa, and strip some architectures, and you can see the real sizes for your customers.